# errors: [ 'All included players are not subscribed' ]

Tags: javascript, node.js, vercel

The goal is to send notifications to users using onsignal-node module, I have this error which persists for days.
Please help me .
[Capture the error in the console](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jCjKN.png)

**I have subscribed users in the segment mentioned**
Here is my code

```
import '../_alias';
import { get } from '@yotie/micron';
import { createLambda } from '../_init';
import { Client } from 'onesignal-node';

export default createLambda(
    get(async ({ }) => {
        const Clients = new Client(`${process.env.APPID}`, `${process.env.APIKEY}`);
        const notification = {
            contents: {
                heading: 'Header Notification',
                en: "Test notification",
                chrome_web_icon: '',
                firefox_icon: ''
            },
            included_segments: ["Subscribed Users"],
        };
        const response = await Clients.createNotification(notification);
        if (response) {
            console.log(response.body)
        } else {
            console.log({ success: false })
        }
    })
);
```

Comment: Possibly your test users are all unsubscribed users? Possibly take out the `included_segments` line and see what happens. Also, you could paste the error directly into the question text, which makes it helpful for people to see it easily :)

Comment: when I delete the line `included_segments` it gives 
 `body: {
    errors: [
      'You must include which players, segments, or tags you wish to send this notification to.'
    ]
  },
  statusCode: 400
}`